# how to un-indent theorems

Tags: indentation

I'm about to deposit my thesis.  The grad school administrators set out formatting requirements and someone from years past wrote some tex files (a document class?) that I'm using to make sure my thesis complies with the formatting requirements.  The only problem is that whatever this person wrote indents every theorem, definition, lemma etc.  So that no matter what I do (actually \noindent is the only thing I know to try), every new theorem looks like this:

[image]

obtained from

```
\documentclass{brandiss}
\newtheorem*{main}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\noindent Here's a non-indented line of text.
\begin{thm}
Here's a Theorem
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

which looks really dumb.  Especially when I state a theorem right after the first sentence of a new paragraph.  Maybe this is impossible to answer without seeing the code for the document class (Actually its right here: http://www.brandeis.edu/departments/mathematics/graduate/current/brandiss.html )

but I was wondering if anyone knows how to fix this.  I recall a few weeks ago I was able to do something that unindented everything, but if I did that I'd have to manually indent every paragraph and its a pretty long document.

Comment: `\parindent=0pt`? But then also the normal paragraph start will be unindented (ok in some part of the world, don't know over there). Anyway, the class seems just a slight overload over amsbook, so if you add a MWE with that class it would be useful to help us help you.

Comment: Could you post a minimal example code?

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, I've added a small bit of example code.  the "brandiss" thing is a file available at the link to Brandeis.edu I gave.

Comment: @Rmano Thanks for your comment. Is this what you mean by MWE?

Comment: Yes. @Bernard, you can just change the class to `amsbook` and it shows the same thing. I think that https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35215/using-the-amsbook-class is related.

Comment: @Rmano: That's normal: the `brandiss` class loads `amsbook`.

Comment: the recommended method for changing the theorem style with `amsbook` (into which is built `amsthm`) is to define a `\newtheoremstyle`.  how to do this is is documented in the `amsthm` user's guide (`texdoc amsthm`). which was completely rewritten about a year ago to give more and clearer examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this (from [this other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230321/remove-indentation-of-theorems)):

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

%%% added in the preamble 
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@thm
  {\let\thm@indent\indent}{\let\thm@indent\noindent}%
  {}{}
\makeatother
%%% end added code 

\newtheorem*{main}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\begin{document}
\noindent Here's a non-indented line of text.
\begin{thm}
Here's a Theorem
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

I checked with `amsbook` but should work for your document class.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any ideas about how to un-indent proofs? (I use \begin{proof} \end{proof}).  I did the dumbest thing possible and replaced "thm" in your code with "proof", but it didn't work.

Comment: nm. I worked something out from the post you linked to in the comments.  Thanks again.