# Indentation and fonts conflict in theorem environment with amsbook

Tags: fonts, indentation, theorems, etoolbox, amsbook

I'm using amsbook package but don't like the indentation at the beginning of theorems and proofs environments.

I've tried to the the solution proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365479), and it works with respect to indents, however, it seems to suppress the font for theorem-like environments in amsbook, namely `\scshape`, instead, it apparently switches back to `\bfseries`.

However, the author of the solution claims that his method does indeed works with amsbook.

I've tried inserting

```
\patchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\scshape}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@opargbegintheorem}{\scshape}{}{}{}
```

manually, but still to no avail.

If one doesn't want to follow the link, then here's the proposed code to remove indentation:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@thm
  {\let\thm@indent\indent}{\let\thm@indent\noindent}%
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

Compiable code:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1.15in, left=1.15in, right=1.15in]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@thm
  {\let\thm@indent\indent}{\let\thm@indent\noindent}%
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\scshape}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@opargbegintheorem}{\scshape}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\proof\endcsname
  {\normalparindent}{0pt }{}{}
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\theorem\endcsname
  {\normalparindent}{0pt }{}{}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks   = true, 
  urlcolor     = blue, 
  linkcolor    = blue, 
  citecolor    = red 
}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand\labelenumi{(\theenumi)}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{proof}
Proof by contradiction. If it wasn't, then I wouldn't put it inside t 
theorem environment.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

I apologize if the question may be in essence stupid, I'm still new to LaTeX.

Comment: Off-topic: you are loading `hyperref` too early.

Comment: the recommended method for changing the theorem style with `amsbook` (into which is built `amsthm`) is to define a `\newtheoremstyle`. how to do this is is documented in the `amsthm` user's guide (`texdoc amsthm`). which was completely rewritten about a year ago to give more and clearer examples.  this question might be a potential duplicate: [how to un-indent theorems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365445/579) although i don't particularly favor the answer.

Comment: @cfr Thanks, I've made some googling, know I now it should be loaded last almost in every case.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's helpful, thanks. I've done what I've wanted to do using  `\newtheoremstyle`. For some reason, before your comment I thought that etoolbox is the better (whatever this word means in this context) way. Apparently, not so much. Concerning duplicates, while my question (though I can see now it is poorly worded) is technically about a different but related issue, I agree that it might count as a duplicate, and I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hooks to change the indent without patching the commands. Here we set `\thm@indent` to `\noindent` before every theorem heading (the command `\@begintheorem`), and as amsbook's `proof` environment indents by `\normalparindent`, we locally set this dimension to zero.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
\AddToHook{cmd/@begintheorem/before}{\let\thm@indent\noindent}
\AddToHook{env/proof/begin}{\setlength{\normalparindent}{0pt}}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

\begin{document}

\chapter{This is}

\kant[1][1]

\begin{theorem}[heading]
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\kant[2][1]

\begin{proof}
Proof by contradiction.
\end{proof}

\kant[3][1]

\end{document}
```

[image: thms]

Note that this solution is specific to the AMS classes.